# Serializing Array of Structs to byte[] - What's Wrong with my Code?

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling, unmanaged-memory

I have a generic method for serializing an array of any `struct` type into an array of `byte`s using `Marshal.StructureToPtr` and `Marshal.Copy`. The full code is:

```
    internal static byte[] SerializeArray<T>(T[] array) where T : struct
    {
        if (array == null)
            return null;
        if (array.Length == 0)
            return null;

        int position = 0;
        int structSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));

        byte[] rawData = new byte[structSize * array.Length];

        IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(structSize);
        foreach (T item in array)
        {
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(item, buffer, false);
            Marshal.Copy(buffer, rawData, position, structSize );
            position += structSize;
        }
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);

        return rawData;
    }
```

It works flawlessly 99.99% of the time. However, for one of my Windows 7 users, with certain input data this code will predictably cause the following non-.NET exception:

> The data area passed to a system call is too small. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x8007007A).

Unfortunately I do not have access to the user's machine in order to attach a debugger, and I have not been able to replicate the issue even when dealing with the exact same input data as my user. This occurs only on the one user's machine and only with certain input data, but on her machine it happens every time with that same input data, so it's definitely not random.

The application targets .NET 4.5.

Can anyone see anything wrong with this code? My only guess is there is some mismatch occurring between what `Marshal.SizeOf` is reporting and the actual size of the data structure, thus leading to insufficient memory being allocated for the structure.

If it matters, here is the structure being serialized when the error occurs (it's a representation of character positions resulting from OCR):

```
public struct CharBox
{
    internal char Character;
    internal float Left;
    internal float Top;
    internal float Right;
    internal float Bottom;
}
```

As you can see all the fields should be constant size all the time, so my initial allocation of a single fixed-length segment of unmanaged memory into which to serialize each `struct` shouldn't be a problem (should it?).

While I would welcome alternative or improved methods of doing the serialization, I'm far more interested in nailing down this particular bug. Thanks!

**Update**
Thanks to TnTnMn's pointing out to me that `char` is not a blittable type, I looked for unicode characters in the input to see if they were marshaling correctly. Turns out, they are NOT.

For the `CharBox { 0x2022, .15782328, .266239136, .164901689, .271627158 },` the serialization (in hex) should be:

> 22 20 00 00 (Character*)
>
> 6D 9C 21 3E (Left)
>
> 7F 50 88 3E (Top)
>
> FD DB 28 3E (Right)
>
> B7 12 8B 3E (Bottom)

(* Since I wasn't using explicit layout, it padded to four bytes; I'm now frustrated with myself for needlessly increasing the data size by 11%...)

Instead, it is serializing as:

> 95 00 00 00 (Character)
>
> 6D 9C 21 3E (Left)
>
> 7F 50 88 3E (Top)
>
> FD DB 28 3E (Right)
>
> B7 12 8B 3E (Bottom)

So it is marshaling `char` 0x2022 as 0x95 instead. As it happens, 0x2022 Unicode and 0x95 ANSI are both the bullet character. Thus this is not random but rather it's marshaling everything to ANSI, which as I now recall is standard procedure if you don't specify a `CharSet`.

Ok, so this at least confirms there is some unintended behavior going on, and further gives us a good working theory as to what conditions (namely, a unicode character in the struct) might be leading to the error.

What it does not explain is why this would raise an exception at all, let alone why it isn't raised on any machine but this one user's. As to the former, a discrepancy in the `byte` size of unciode vs. ANSI would, I suppose, be consistent with the error message ("The data area passed to a system call is too small"), but the unmanaged buffer - which is sized to accommodate 4 full bytes for the `char`, would be larger than necessary, not smaller. Why would the CLR or the OS be upset about writing only 1 byte to an area intended for 2 and large enough for 4?

As to the latter, I thought perhaps the user might be on a lower version of .NET than everyone else, which could be the case if she's not getting all the Windows 7 updates. But I just tried it out on a VM with a fresh Windows 7 install and .NET 4.5 (the lowest version the application supports) and still can't reproduce the error. I'm trying to find out exactly what .NET version she's got in case it's 4.5.1 or something. Still, this seems like a long shot.

It seems the only way to know for sure will be to change the `Character` member to an `int` (to keep the padding the same for existing data) and only cast it to `char` when necessary, and then see if that changes the result on the user's machine. This'll also be a good opportunity to wrap each distinct `Marshal` call in an exception handler as John suggested to see which, exactly, is causing the error.

The good news is this is a pretty low priority feature, so I can let it fail safely even if it continues to occur.

Will report back.  Thanks all.

Comment: Is the `CharBox`  in the same DLL or EXE where the SerializeArray() function is getting called? If not, then `internal` is your problem I would think.

Comment: It's in the same module.

Comment: OK, next step would be to pinpoint which of the system calls is throwing that exception. When we use marshall, we religiously use try..catch statements around each call. Then you'll know where to look next. There could be all kinds of reasons for this generic error.

Comment: I would also trap the case where structSize  could be 0 - weird, but hey... you got to check until you can diagnose.

Comment: Structsize is definitely not zero here, but for the generic case sure it's an improvement to check for that.  I can and will wrap the individual Marshal calls in exception handlers as the next step, but I'm trying to minimize the amount of trial and error I have to put my customer through. Truth is the code is very straightforward and should either be sound or not. If it is sound them it's a bug in the framework and I need to use a different approach entirely.

Comment: There is one thing in your code that has been nagging at the back of my mind: passing false for the `fDeleteOld` argument in [StructureToPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zhzfk83(v=vs.110).aspx).  This due to the warning about a possible memory leak if false is used.  The doc's for [DestroyStructure ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/df3k5fh1(v=vs.110).aspx) imply no problem if all structure types are blittable.  But the issue is that `System.Char` is not blittable; see: [Blittable and Non-Blittable Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx).

Comment: @Peter, I get it. I have similar situations. The next shot means you must have all questionable calls wrapped by try catch and logged so that when it happens you don't ask the client again for a test. I know it's embarrassing, but sometimes that's what you have to do. Your code looks fine to me as others also pointed out. Memory leak could be a problem, but normally you get the system out of memory exception. Would be good to print the memory usage usage in your catch as well. or try something completely different. Maybe reinstall .net (oh no, not _that_ answer :) kidding)

Comment: @TnTinMn I think you might be on to something here. I'm sure this is not a memory leak (it happens with very small documents even right after the program starts). But I did not realize char was not blittable. I wonder if the issue is related to there being unicode characters in the input set - which marshal as two bytes - versus ansi characters which marshal as 1. I'm going to try changing the char in the struct to a short, and using explicit alignment. Thanks for the tip on blitting!

Comment: I didn't know that Char was not blittable either until I tried my first attempt at an alternative with getting a pinned GCHandle to the array.  That would have reduced this down to a single Marshal.Copy call.  I also don't know if what you are currently doing would cause a leak, but my intent was point out that there could be some alignment issue going on which you appear to be leaning towards now as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well I found a solution that worked, though I still don't know why.

Here's what I changed. `CharBox` is now:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct CharBox
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal int Character;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    internal float Left;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    internal float Top;

    [FieldOffset(12)]
    internal float Right;

    [FieldOffset(16)]
    internal float Bottom;

    // Assists with error reporting
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"CharBox (Character = {this.Character}, Left = {this.Left}, Top = {this.Top}, Right = {this.Right}, Bottom = {this.Bottom})";
    }
}
```

And the actual method is now:

```
    internal static byte[] SerializeArray<T>(T[] array) where T : struct
    {
        if ( array.IsNullOrEmpty() )
            return null;            

        int position = 0;
        int structSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));

        if (structSize < 1)
        {
            throw new Exception($"SerializeArray: invalid structSize ({structSize})");
        }

        byte[] rawData = new byte[structSize * array.Length];
        IntPtr buffer = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
        {
            buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(structSize);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"SerializeArray: Marshal.AllocHGlobal(structSize={structSize}) failed. Message: {ex.Message}");
        }

        try
        {
            int i = 0;
            int total = array.Length;
            foreach (T item in array)
            {
                try
                {
                    Marshal.StructureToPtr(item, buffer, false);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"SerializeArray: Marshal.StructureToPtr failed. item={item.ToString()}, index={i}/{total}. Message: {ex.Message}");
                }

                try
                {
                    Marshal.Copy(buffer, rawData, position, structSize);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"SerializeArray: Marshal.Copy failed. item={item.ToString()}, index={i}/{total}. Message: {ex.Message}");
                }

                i++;
                position += structSize;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Marshal.FreeHGlobal failed (buffer={buffer}. Message: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        return rawData;
    }
```

I was expecting just to get more detail on the error, but instead the user reported that it worked without any warning.

All the changes to `SerializeArray` were just for more detailed reporting, so the substantive changes, one or more of which were the winners, were:

- Changing the `char` to an `int` (I would have used `short` but I wanted to stay compatible with existing data since this `struct` is used elsewhere, and previously it was using 4-byte padding).
- Setting the `struct` layout to `LayoutKind.Explicit` and setting the explicit `FieldOffset`s; and
- Specifying `CharSet.Unicode` in `StructLayout` - which admittedly probably did nothing since there are no more `char`'s in the `struct`

My guess is that setting the layout to `Explicit` and the `CharSet` to Unicode would have been enough to allow `Character` to be a `char` again, but I'd rather not waste my customer's time with more trial and error since it is working. Hopefully someone else can opine as to what happened, but I'll probably post this to MSDN too in the hopes that one of the CLR gods might have some insight.

Thanks all especially TnTnMan because highlighting the issue with `char`s and blitting definitely motivated me trying these changes.

Comment: For future reference, now that your structure only contains blittable types, you can use `gchnd = GCHandle.Alloc(array, GCHandleType.Pinned)` to obtain a GCHandle instance.  Then you can do a single `Marshal.Copy(gchnd.AddrOfPinnedObject, rawData, 0, rawData.Length)` to load the byte array.  No need to copy each item.  You can use the same technique to recreate the array from a byte array.

Comment: Oh that's a great idea thank you. If you want feel free to post that as an answer because that is probably the best approach of all.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any obvious error in your existing methodology, so I have nothing to offer on that front. However since you stated:

> I would welcome alternative or improved methods of doing the serialization

I would like to throw this out for your consideration.  Use a [MemoryMappedViewAccessor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedviewaccessor(v=vs.110).aspx) to perform the transformation from array of structures to byte array.  This of course requires creating a [MemoryMappedFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
internal static byte[] SerializeArray<T>(T[] array) where T : struct
    {
    int unmananagedSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));

    int numBytes = array.Length * unmananagedSize;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[numBytes];

    using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("fred", bytes.Length))
        {
        using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(0, bytes.Length, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {

            accessor.WriteArray<T>(0, array, 0, array.Length);
            accessor.ReadArray<byte>(0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            }
        }

    return bytes;
    }

internal static T[] DeSerializeArray<T>(byte[] bytes) where T : struct
    {
    int unmananagedSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));

    int numItems = bytes.Length / unmananagedSize;
    T[] newArray = new T[numItems];

    using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("fred", bytes.Length))
        {
        using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(0, bytes.Length, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {

            accessor.WriteArray<byte>(0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            accessor.ReadArray<T>(0, newArray, 0, newArray.Length);

            }
        }
    return newArray;
    }
```

Depending on you usage, you may need to provide a mechanism for a unique name (where I used "fred") for the MemoryMappedFile.

Comment: Well that gets an upvote for originality! I'll try it out, thanks. Still hoping to nail down what I'm doing wrong here though (or if there's a bug in the framework).

Comment: that's a shared memory segment! Overkill...... and curious/doubtful about performance.

Comment: @john, I ran a few tests on Win 10 /64.  Compiled as a 32 bit assembly, the MMF technique took about twice as long to run as the OP's version at 3.32 ms vs 1.75 ms to process 10000 items.  When compiled as a 64 bit assembly, the MMF technique very slightly out performed the original version 1.48 ms vs 1.56 ms.  Now if the Char fikled is changed to a property that maps to a blittable integer, the OP's method takes about half the time it previously did and the MMF times stayed the same.

Comment: @TnTinMn you just have too much time on your hands ;) Next problem: not multi thread friendly ;). Interesting approach though

Comment: Would have been interesting to try your commented suggestion of `gchnd.AddrOfPinnedObject()` too, which seems to work *way* faster than the original loop solution in the question, or the memory map.